# Superhero comic where a brother and sister rob a jewelry store

Tags: story-identification, comics

Ages ago, I read a superhero comic that I only remember one scene from.  I think it was DC, not Marvel, but I really couldn't say for sure.  In the comic, there were these two villain characters who rob a jewelry store.  They're a brother and sister, both blonde, and have similar styles of their outfits.  They didn't have elaborate costumes.  The scene I remember is the two of them in the jewelry store (I think it was in a mall) where the sister points out a necklace she likes in a glass case.  The saleman says that it's two thousand dollars, and the brother says that it wouldn't be any skin off of their noses.  The salesman then says "Well, allow me to ring it up for your beautiful lady friend."  The brother then hurls the salesman at the wall, saying "Watch your mouth, that's my sister you're talking about."  The sister punches through the glass to grab the necklace and says "I said wrap it up, not ring it up.  It's not like we're paying or anything."

I wish I could remember more, but that's it.  It's been on my mind and I'd like to trace it.

Comment: DC sibling thieves, the brother being protective of the sister and the sister not having a care in the world? Sounds like the Snart siblings (Captain Cold/Golden Glider). Now *which* issue would that be, though - no idea, and Google queries are fruitless so far. When would that have been published, roughly?

Comment: They are brunette, but for some reason I am put in mind of some of the 80s sibling drama of Marvel's Northstar and Aurora from Alpha Flight.

Comment: They're Marvel, but the description and interaction remind me of Fenris, aka Andrea and Andreas Von Strucker. They've had many appearances over the years, but quite often have appeared wearing very similar clothing. Give them a Google to see if you recognise them. If its them and you can pinpoint their appearance, you may have a chance of pinpointing the actual comic.

Comment: My first thought is the Tornado Twins.  Super speedsters that are usually more heroic than not, but with endless universe reboots, they could easily become arrogant snots with thieving attitudes.